# Show that two field extensions are the same

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, rational-numbers

Can you help me with showing that these two field extensions are the same:

1. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt[3]{5})$
2. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3} + b\sqrt[3]{5})$, where  $b\neq0$ is any rational number.

Thanks

Comment: In general, they are not the same. It depends on which $b$ you pick. (Though picking wrong is not easy)

Comment: $b=0$ certainly won't work.

Comment: Generally, you want to look at $(\sqrt{3} + b \sqrt[3]{5})^2$, $(\sqrt{3} + b \sqrt[3]{5})^3$ etc. and see if you can get a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear combination of them which equals $\sqrt{3}$. As @HagenvonEitzen mentioned, this is not always possible, e.g. $b=0$.

Comment: yes, it cannot be 0, but still @AlexGrounds i tried that way but unseccessfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\alpha=\sqrt 3+b\sqrt[3]5$.
Clearly, $\mathbb Q(\alpha)\subseteq \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt[3]5)$.
Let $\beta=\sqrt 3$. Then 
$$5b^3=(\alpha-\beta)^3=\alpha^3-3\alpha^2\beta+9\alpha-3\beta $$
shows that (NB $\alpha^2+1\ne0$)
$$ \beta = \frac{\alpha^3+9\alpha-5b^3}{3(\alpha^2+1)}\in\mathbb Q(\alpha)$$
and (since $b\ne0$) then also $$ \sqrt[3]5=\frac{\alpha-\beta}{b}\in\mathbb Q(\alpha).$$